# Mysql return 1 if value found or not at all present, If other values present, return 0

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to get all the students' details who either are in room number 6 or 7 or not at all in any room. If they are in other rooms, simply, I don't wish to have that record.
My schema is:

```
students(roll_no, name,class,...)
rooms(room_no,...)
student_room(room_no,roll_no).
```

students and rooms are related via `student_room` table.
But, I am unable to figure out how to write the query for this.

Comment: How is the rooms table linked with other tables?

Comment: `I am unable to figure out how to write the query for this` ... and so are we unless you give us your schema.

Comment: Your schema seems to incorrect as students and rooms are not realtes to each other as per the schema you posted

Comment: schema is not correct, post full detail

Comment: Thanks all for initiative. Well, I have edited the qs. as well as figured out an answer.

Comment: SELECT effort FROM others WHERE homework = 'yours';

Comment: @Strawberry.. sometimes you have to. when you can't figure out the answer yourself. But one must try first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you details of the students that are in rooms other than 6 or 7:

```
SELECT
  s.*
FROM
  student AS s
  INNER JOIN student_room AS sr ON s.roll_no = sr.roll_no
WHERE
  sr.room_no NOT IN (6, 7)
;
```

Now you just need to invert this logic to return the other subset. This is called an anti-join. There is no direct syntax for it in SQL but there are several ways of implementing it using existing syntax. If we take the above query as a starting point, the closest matching anti-join form would be the `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL` method:

```
SELECT
  s.*
FROM
  student AS s
  LEFT JOIN student_room AS sr ON s.roll_no = sr.roll_no
                              AND sr.room_no NOT IN (6, 7)
WHERE
  sr.roll_no IS NULL
;
```

This is how it works:

1. The result of the join itself will contain *all* students from the `student` table, as that table is on the left side of a left outer join.
2. The right side of the join will have data only if the corresponding student is not in room 6 or 7. Otherwise it will contain nulls.
3. The matching rows are excluded in the WHERE clause by checking that there is *no match* on the right side (`sr.roll_no IS NULL`; it would work the same with `sr.roll_no IS NULL` provided `sr.roll_no` cannot have nulls).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
SELECT * FROM students 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT roll_no,CASE WHEN room_no=6 or room_no=7 THEN 1 
        WHEN room_no IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS is_room
 from student_room GROUP BY roll_no) AS room_info
ON students.roll_no=room_info.roll_no 
AND room_info.is_room=1
```